# passing this into a closure

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm using the javascript module pattern, and returning all functions as object members, and I'm trying to add a closure for an on change handler using d3, but this is outside of the scope in the closure I'm using for a handler and I'm not sure how to put it in scope.  So my module looks like:

```
var myMod = (function() {
    return {
        onChangeHandler: function(x, y) {
            // handle event
        },

        createSelect: function(columnName) {
            // create the select form element as categorySelect using d3

            // add event handler using d3 api

            // this version works, but the d3 arguments aren't the ones I want
            categorySelect.on("change, this.onChangeHandler);

            // so this is what I actually want
            categorySelect.on("change", function() {
                // but this gives an error
                this.onChangeHandler(columnName);
            });
        }
    };
})();
```

The error I get with the second version is:

> TypeError: this.categoryFieldChanged is not a function

So I think I need to pass `this` into the closure, but I don't control the arguments that get passed into the closure, so how do I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Just worked it out having typed it all in (of course).  But to share the answer:

I can store `this` in a variable in the scope of the outer function that **is** then available inside the closure.  For example:

```
    createSelect: function(columnName) {
        // create the select form element as categorySelect using d3

        // add event handler using d3 api
        var moduleThis = this;
        categorySelect.on("change", function() {
            // but this gives an error
            moduleThis.onChangeHandler(columnName);
        });
    }
```

I've also discovered that `this` inside the closure refers to the select, so I can get the newly selected value with `this.value`